# Changing the output of APT to contain the repository from where it originates

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I have a few repositories that are added to the sources other than the original. After updating, doing an apt search gives me a list like this:

> snp-sites/disco 2.4.1-1 amd64
>     Binary code for the package snp-sites
>
> sparse/disco 0.6.0-3 amd64
>     semantic parser of source files
>
> sparse-test-inspect/disco 0.6.0-3 amd64
>     semantic parser of source files
>
> stalin/disco 0.11-6build1 amd64
>     An extremely aggressive Scheme compiler
>
> tcc/disco 0.9.27-8 amd64
>     small ANSI C compiler

Is it possible to get apt to display the repository source as well? As in can the maintainers add a feature to display the repository source